# Should I place ferrite barrel/ring on my Nokia 5110 module data lines?

Tags: ferrite

I have Nokia 5110 LCD module from AliExpress. My motherboard is ruled by ATmega64A and control pins for LCD are grouped together as pin header (male, 8 pins in total). The module itself is placed on the external side of plastic case and will be connected with 8-wire ribbon cable (female-to-female).

My question is: should I place ferrite barrel (or make few turns of 8 wires on ferrite ring) to reduce EMI/RFI as it usually done on VGA, DVI and USB cables?

Comment: Well, have you measured if it does emit too much EMI/RFI so it needs to be reduced? Do you need to pass EMI/RFI testing?

Comment: @Justme no, I'm asking not because of compliance issues but because I want to know if it will help to prevent glitches caused by EMI/RFI when my connection ribbon cable is quite long (about 0.5m).

Comment: If you have glitches on the display due to long wires, I don't think placing a ferrite will solve that. The ferrites are not on VGA/DVI/USB cables to preventing glitches, but to prevent EMI/RFI.

Comment: Okay, it seems like I start to understand ferrite stuff. I've always thought that all sensitive data cables (especially long) such as USB use ferrites to block unwanted RFI/EMI and only now I've realized that these barrels block *outgoing* emissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you have unwanted glitches, a ferrite would not solve it.

The ferrites are on cables to keep conducted and radiated EMI/RFI within limits for regulatory compliance reasons.

What will affect more is what kind of cable is used, whether the cable is shielded and if the electrical signals are properly driven and terminated to have reliable communication between them.

Comment: This LCD module doesn't provide any shield connection point. Also the internal schematics are not known so I can't say anything about termination of signal paths. I only know that it should be driven directly with MCU at CMOS logic level.

I will use simple set of 8 unshielded wires (0.35 mm²) soldered to the female connectors. My plan is to twist them together to reduce space

Comment: @drobotviktor -- Ethernet cable does very well at reducing glitches, but it's full of twisted-pairs. If you can do likewise, you will have your glitch-free comms.